# Excel Live updates

Tags: excel

I have an excel file where I do a look up from a table with partial matches using the code

> =VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE("*",D4,"*"),Sheet3!A3:H352,1,FALSE)

Where I look at the contents of cell D4 and try to match it with the table on Sheet3. I'm searching for a name in the table on sheet3.

I am trying to find a way to update the value of this cell as D4 is typed without having to press enter after typing the value into cell D4.

i.e. If a name on Sheet3 is David English, then as I am typing

> Eng

into the box, I would like David English to show up "live" on that cell.

Answer (score 0):

No formula evaluation will happen in Excel while you type in a cell. You need to confirm data entry in the cell before the Vlookup can be recalculated. That is how Excel formulas work.